# Deriving laplacian in spherical coordinates using matrix operations

Tags: calculus, laplacian

I'm reading through [this page](http://planetmath.org/derivationofthelaplacianfromrectangulartosphericalcoordinates) and though I haven't checked all the computations I got the idea. I was wondering if the same result could be derived in a similar fascion

The Jacobian that transform rectangular into spherical coordinates is given by

$$
J = \frac{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial(x,y,z)} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) & \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) & \cos(\theta) \\
\frac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) & \frac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) & -\frac{1}{r}\sin(\theta) \\
-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\sin(\theta)} & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\cos(\phi)}{\sin(\theta)} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Therefore we have

$$
\nabla_c f = \left( J \cdot \nabla_s\right) f \Rightarrow \nabla_c = \left( J \cdot \nabla_s\right)
$$

where
$$
\nabla_c = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}, \nabla_s = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Therefore we have

$$
\left(\nabla_c^T \cdot \nabla_c \right) = \left( J \cdot \nabla_s\right)^T \cdot \left( J \cdot \nabla_s\right) = \left(\nabla_s^T \cdot J^T \cdot J \cdot \nabla_s \right) \Rightarrow \left(\nabla_c^T \cdot \nabla_c \right) = \left(\nabla_s^T \cdot J^T \cdot J \cdot \nabla_s \right)
$$

Hence we have

$$
\nabla_c^2 f = \left(\nabla_s^T \cdot J^T \cdot J \cdot \nabla_s \right) f
$$

Is there anything I could do to use the last equation to work out the laplacian in spherical coordinates? as it is usually stated I mean.